# Web3.js not accepting const variable as 'from:' address in action creator

Tags: javascript, redux, ethereum, redux-thunk, web3js

I am trying to pass a props object (a contract address held in the redux store) into an action creator, and use that props object as the 'from:' address. However, if I don't pass through the raw string of the address manually, I get a "no from address specified"

I have passed the plain address through and the action creator works great. Whenever I give it the variable. I get the error.

```
//ACTION CREATOR
export const createOrgAndContract = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const account = await getState().web3connect.account;
    console.log(account);
    const createContract = await orgFactory.methods.createOrg(id).send({ from: `${account}` });
    const contractAddress = createContract.events.orgCreated.returnValues.newAddress;
    const response = await localDB.post(`/orgs`, { id, contractAddress });

    dispatch({ type: CREATE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, payload: response.data });
};
```

Here's another way I've tried, still the same output:

```
//ACTION CREATOR V2
export const createOrgAndContract = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const account = await getState().web3connect.account;
    console.log(account);
    const createContract = await orgFactory.methods.createOrg(id).send({ from: account });
    const contractAddress = createContract.events.orgCreated.returnValues.newAddress;
    const response = await localDB.post(`/orgs`, { id, contractAddress });

    dispatch({ type: CREATE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, payload: response.data });
};
```

And here's the web3connect.account object in the redux store (if i replace 'account' with just this address, everything works great):

```
{
  account: '0xB59EaB6A9C3AAC2dba42491502A0699c7b03A857'
}
```

And here's the error I get

```
index.js:756 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
```

Anybody know why this variable isn't qualifying as a "from" address in web3.js?